# sed awk get substring instead - regex

Tags: regex, sed, awk

Hi how to use sed or awk to extract substring that matches a regular expression.

I have seen several modify or change substring but I just want to get the matching part.

my data looks like below:

```
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap1.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap2.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap3.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap4.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap5.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap6.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap7.gz</loc>
<loc>http://www.A.com/sitemap8.gz</loc>
```

Output should look like

```
http://www.A.com/sitemap1.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap2.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap3.gz
....
```

I tried

```
cat data | sed 's/'http.*gz'//'
```

but this command actually removes exactly the part that I want to keep. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `grep` will do with the `-o` option:

```
$ grep -o 'http[^<]*' file
http://www.A.com/sitemap1.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap2.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap3.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap4.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap5.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap6.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap7.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap8.gz
```

With `awk` you could do:

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}' file
http://www.A.com/sitemap1.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap2.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap3.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap4.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap5.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap6.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap7.gz
http://www.A.com/sitemap8.gz
```

Comment: if I am understanding it correctly, ^ is like the denying symbol, so s match until come across '<'. If '<' exists in the html, however could I put a word on the blacklist, say http[^<loc], would that work? or it will stop not only for <, but also for l, o, or c

Comment: Correct however `<loc` won't be treated as a word but a set of characters known as a character class.

Comment: how could you treated as a word? that would be very helpful

Comment: You would want [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) @anubhava answer uses positive lookahead and behind. To match any string that doesn't follow a given word you would want negative lookahead. Lookarounds aren't part of BRE *(Basic Regular Expression)* nor even ERE *(Extended Regular Expression)* so check that your language/environment supports them.

Answer (score 2):

This sed should work:

```
sed 's/^.*\(http.*gz\).*$/\1/' file
```

OR grep -P (--perl-regexp) can also do the job:

```
grep -Po '(?<=<loc>).*?(?=</loc>)' file
```